Text Classification Task with already masked text
Hello all I am working on a project of NLP text classification (a domain specific data). The task is of binary classification around 8000 data points but only 80 labeled. Moreover some parts of the data are already masked. I have cleaned and preprocessed the data and even tokenised it using word2vec. How should I go about it, please shed some light. How should self supervised learning be used if it is the way to go.
